# Write a function count(number, array, length) that will count the number of times number appears in array

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm completing the problem sets out of an o'reilly textbook on my own and I'm a bit confused on what I'm supposed to be doing with this program.
The question is: Write a function `count(number, array, length)` that will count the number of times number appears in `array`. the array has `length` elements. The function should be recursive. Write a test program to go with the function.

The question is copied word for word, but I have a few questions about this question. if you could leave a comment stating your opinion about the following, that would be nice:

1. Okay, I need an `array` with length `length`, do I store my own numbers in the slots? or do I generate random integers to go in the slots?
2. also, do I have the right plan? My plan is to:

create the array and call `count` in main.
the function `count` will be an if loop that goes through the array until it finds `number` it will then add one to a counter. then the `count` function will call it's self with the parameters `count(int number; int array; int (length - 1))`

Now that I try to talk myself through it, I am now even more confused. Maybe I'm just making the question more difficult. Any tips will help. Thanks

Comment: 1. `array` is an input to the problem, so you can fake one, like what segfolt did, or you can generate random integers, which you will likely to get 0 as output. 2. your solution may work if you change the call to `count(int number, int *new_array, int new_length)`, where `new_array` points to the next element after you find one `number`, and `new_length` is equal the length from 'new_array' to the end of `array`. But I think segfolt's code is clearer as a recursive solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a code snippet worth more than a lot of words. So I would go for something like that:

```
#include <iostream>

int count(int num, int* arr, int length) {
    if (!length)
        return 0;
    int c = count(num, arr+1, length-1);
    return arr[0] == num? c + 1: c;
}

int main(void) {
    int arr[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2};

    std::cout << count(2, arr, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: This was a lot easier than I was making it. Although the book hasn't got to pointers, this is as simple as it gets. Thanks.

Comment: @Maurice Abney: Glad I could help :)

Comment: @MauriceAbney: if you don't want to mess around with the array pointer, you could do the following instead: `int count(int num, int* arr, int length) {
  if (!length)
   return 0;
  int c = count(num, arr, --length);
  return arr[length] == num? c + 1: c;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

1. To test whether your function is right yes, you can use your own numbers in the array. It's just important that the algorithm works.
2. Nope your approach is wrong. Recursion has two parts:

a) The clause about what you know

b) The clause about what you could know if you change what you have.

So in your case the function `count(.....)` should at first get to know whether the `length` is 0 because then the number `number` is 0 times in `array`. If it is not, you need to call your function `count(.....)` with `number` as the number (cause you still want to count the same number) the `array` except for the last element of the array and `length-1`. That recursively shovels down the array until it has no more items in it.

~ short break, to let the brain refresh ~

You should save the return value of the function in a variable, and afterwards add 1 if the last item of `array` is `number`, otherwise not. And again return that value. Now this value is passed backwards through all the function calls and incremented if the arrayelement we are looking at is the `number`. The original call to `count(....)` returns the number of `number`s in `array`

I hope I have no fails in my explanation.